# How can I compare two dates in batch?

Tags: date, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I have a batch script to get two dates; one of a folder, and the current system date.

I want to specifically compare the two by seeing if the date of the folder is 10 minutes or less older than the current date. This essentially checks if the user has modified this folder at the most 10 minutes ago.

Here's my current code (not complete, but the base):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%a/%%b/%%c)
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a:%%b)

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if exist "C:\$Recycle.Bin" (
    pushd "C:\$Recycle.Bin"
    for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /S /b S-1-*-1001 /AD') do (set "{recycle-bin-date}=%%a")
    for %%a in ("!{recycle-bin-date}!") do (
        Set "data=%%~ta"
    )
    popd
)

set date1=%mydate% %mytime%
set date2=!data!

echo Date 1 (Current): %date1%
echo Date 2 (Recycle): %date2%
pause

::We have the dates above, how do I achieve what I'm trying to do?
```

If anyone could help me here, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: You should use PowerShell instead, which exposes file system directories as _objects_ with _date_ properties that can be compared directly (no string parsing!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **CAN** do date time math in pure batch but it is quite cumbersome.
(See [Ritchie Lawrence batch function library](https://ritchielawrence.github.io/batchfunctionlibrary/#date-and-time-functions))

I recommend to use PowerShell as a tool for this

PowerShell one liner:

```
[int]([datetime]::Now - (gci 'c:\$Recycle.BIN\S-1-*1001' -Force).LastWriteTime).TotalMinutes
```

Wrapped in a batch

```
@Echo off
For /f "usebackq" %%A in (`
  Powershell -NoP -C "[int]([datetime]::Now - (gci 'c:\$Recycle.BIN\S-1-*1001' -Force).LastWriteTime).TotalMinutes"
`) Do Set "AgeMinutes=%%A"
Echo Age in minutes %AgeMinutes%
```

Comment: Why bother running PowerShell from cmd.exe when you can just do everything in PowerShell?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Well the question **IS** tagged [batch-file] and I think a working example opposed to the tedious wrapping might attract users to switch rather than a simple `powershell is better`. I'm myself an example, my reputation gained from tags switched this week to powershell on 1st place.

Comment: The point is: If you're going to fudge running PowerShell from a batch script, why bother doing that? You have PowerShell already; use it and dispense with the batch script.